# Image not updated in Email Template using Send Grid on Azure Function c#

Tags: c#, image, azure, email, sendgrid

email.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
   .....
  <footer>
  <p> Thank You! <br/> </p>
  <center><img src="https://test.blob.core.windows.net/images/sample.png + SAS token/></center>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read Email template

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("email.html");

// message object
SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage() {
    From = new EmailAddress(from, "Testing"),
    Subject = subject,
    HtmlContent = content
};
```

When I update the Image in https://test.blob.core.windows.net/images/sample.png on Blob storage with the same name (sample.png). I am not able to see the update image in the Email.

What is the exact issue here?

Comment: Do you mean the updated image is not seen in the old email that has already been sent out before the image is updated?

Comment: @GauravMantri No. After image updated in the blob storage, I don't see updated image in email after sending. But I see updated image when I hit the Image URL with sas token used in the email.html after updation of image in blob storage.

Comment: I have recreated the sas token for the image and updated it. Then it works.